# Scene2D: How to add a background image to a table?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to create a splash page with a loading animation for some sprite batches as part of the AssetManager.

I have successfully created a loading animation bar that scales to represent a percentage bar.

My question is in regards to laying it out on the scene. I decided to go with a table that scales to the width of the scene, which is set to the width of the viewport.

I have added my animation actor to the table, however how to set a background image to the table itself?

Answer (score 6):

`Table.setBackground()` will do what you need. It works best (IMO) with a NinePatch, but takes a Drawable.